# Angular does not display data in an output html file

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have app.js file that contains the following code:

```
(function () {
var app = angular.module('store', []);

app.controller('StoreController', function () {
    this.product = gem;
});

var gem = {
    name: 'Dodechaedron',
    price: 2.95,
    description: '...',
};
```

})();

I also have the following html file that contains the following code:

```
<div ng-app="StoreController as store">
    <h1>{{store.product.name}}</h1>
    <h2>{{store.product.price}}</h2>
    <p>{{store.product.description}}</p>
</div>
<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

it also includes

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="store">
```

When I build the app - nothing happens. The question is - where is mi data from the app.js file?

Thank you.

Comment: What are you doing with `StoreController as store`?

Comment: I call the StoreController and give it the alias - store

Comment: I would recommend using `$scope` variables to store data and keep static data like above in its own factory/service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `ng-app` instead of `ng-controller`. If your change your html to this it should work:

```
<div ng-controller="StoreController as store">
```

Answer (score 1):

Your app name should be `store`.

`<html ng-app='store'>`

`StoreController` is a controller so it should be used in `ng-controller`